# Can't do anything with apt without an error caused by shim-signed

Tags: apt, secure-boot

Suppose I type,

```
 sudo apt-get install SOME_PACKAGE
```

Regardless of what package I'm installing, I end up with the following error:

```
    Setting up shim-signed (1.51.3+15.7-0ubuntu1) ...
/var/lib/dpkg/info/shim-signed.postinst: 165: /usr/lib/grub/grub-multi-install: not found
dpkg: error processing package shim-signed (--configure):
 installed shim-signed package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 127
Errors were encountered while processing:
 shim-signed
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I turned off secure boot, rebooted, and tried to uninstall shim-signed, but got:

```
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  shim-signed*
WARNING: The following essential packages will be removed.
This should NOT be done unless you know exactly what you are doing!
  shim-signed
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 to remove and 40 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 4,841 kB disk space will be freed.
E: Removing essential system-critical packages is not permitted. This might break the system.
```

From looking online it appeared that `grub-multi-install` was part of `grub-common`, so I tried grub-multi-install, with the result being the error about `shim-signed` and grub-multi-install.

Anyone else been through this?

This all started after I did

```
apt-get upgrade
apt-get update
```

Anyone else have this problem?